# How to exclude routes from the geocode result?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-geocoder, geocode

I am trying to get the lat and lng of a UK address which I am submitting via a form. The address could be a full address, or a city, or a postcode, or the first part of a postcode.

Most geocode requests seem to give me the correct output however if I try to search for M25, the geocode gives me the wrong results as it thinks it is a motorway in london while I am actually trying to find an area within manchester.

Is there a way to exclude searching within motorways?

My code:

```
public function get_geocode($address) {
        $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.',uk&key='.theme_option('theme_options','theme_options_google_api_key');
            $data = @file_get_contents($url);
        $jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
        if (!$this->get_geocode_check_status($jsondata))   return array();
        $location = array(
            'lat' => $jsondata["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
            'lng' => $jsondata["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"],
        );
        return $location;
    }
```

The lat and lng generated from the code above will be added to an sql query to get the nearest locations stored in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Do you send only postal code prefix M5? In this case the query is too ambiguous and geocoding service doesn't  work well with ambiguous requests. If you specify something more precise it will work (e.g. M5 4GP, UK)

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=M5%204GP%2C%20UK&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Also note that I added the UK in search text in order to bias results towards UK.

In your case when you have only postal code prefix M5, I would suggest using place  autocomplete request as a workaround. It will return several suggestions and you can filter out suggestion that have type "postal_code_prefix" or "postal_code". For example, the request for "M5, UK"

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=M5%2C%20UK&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

returns 5 suggestions, one of them has type "postal_code_prefix"

```
{
  "description":"Salford M5, UK",
  "id":"6cea0bf4efcd39449020500f97a2352cdfd13457",
  "matched_substrings":[
    {
      "length":2,
      "offset":8
    },
    {
      "length":2,
      "offset":12
    }
  ],
  "place_id":"ChIJEVdF_g2ue0gRXkpo4zmLlQM",
  "reference":"ChIJEVdF_g2ue0gRXkpo4zmLlQM",
  "structured_formatting":{
    "main_text":"M5",
    "main_text_matched_substrings":[
      {
        "length":2,
        "offset":0
      }
    ],
    "secondary_text":"Salford, UK",
    "secondary_text_matched_substrings":[
      {
        "length":2,
        "offset":9
      }
    ]
  },
  "terms":[
    {
      "offset":0,
      "value":"Salford"
    },
    {
      "offset":8,
      "value":"M5"
    },
    {
      "offset":12,
      "value":"UK"
    }
  ],
  "types":[
    "postal_code_prefix","postal_code","geocode"
  ]
},
```

Once you filtered this result and got a place ID `ChIJEVdF_g2ue0gRXkpo4zmLlQM` you can reverse geocode it to get coordinates

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJEVdF_g2ue0gRXkpo4zmLlQM&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Have a look at this result in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJEVdF_g2ue0gRXkpo4zmLlQM

I hope this helps!

Comment: I decided to go down the geocomplete route to validate my search before it gets passed to my geocode curl request